# What is the name of this music from the Grand Theft Auto Online Christmas tree?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, game-music-identification

The bunker Christmas tree in Grand Theft Auto Online plays music. I can recognize Deck the Halls and Jingle Bells, but I don't recognize the third one. It's instrumental music only, which you can hear at 27 seconds in this YouTube Video:

Comment: This question is being discussed [on Meta](//meta.arqade.com/q/14803/144891)

Answer (score 4):

It is [The Boar’s Head Carol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boar%27s_Head_Carol), a 15th century English Christmas carol.

Wikipedia has samples here:

- [A Carol Brynging in the Bore's Heed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:A_Carol_Brynging_in_the_Bore%27s_Heed.ogg)
- [The Boar's Head Carol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Boar%27s_Head_Carol.ogg)